# Partition a data frame by time window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, optimization

I have a data frame with a column of the date:

[image]

I would like to partition the DF into 3 DF based on time:

1. 00:00-12:00.
2. 12:00-18:00.
3. 18:00:00:00.

How can it be achieved without a loop?

I could implement this by using a loop over each time stamp, yet it was very slow.

A sample data could be generated by:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-01-10', freq='10min'))
df['data'] = np.random.randint(100, size=len(df))
df.columns = ['date', 'data']
```

Comment: Images of data are not accepted, please provide a [mre] of your input

Comment: @mozway, OK, I will add a CSV link.

Comment: Don link your csv file. Nobody downlaod your file to answer your question. Please take the time and effort to create a [mre] to receive an answer. It is not difficult. "questioner's no effort = no answer."

Comment: @PandaKim, OK, I created a simple code to generate a CSV with the date as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another alternative. You could just filter the dataframe using pandas to yield three new dataframes for the times you want.  I borrowed @mozway's simulated input so please give them credit.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DateWithTime': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-01-10', freq='10min')})
df['Hour']= df['DateWithTime'].dt.hour
df1=df[df['Hour'].isin(range(0,13))]
df2=df[df['Hour'].isin(range(13,19))]
df3=df[df['Hour'].isin(range(19,25))]


display(df)
display(df1)
display(df2)
display(df3)
```

Here is the orginal df and the filtered ones.

```
    DateWithTime    Hour
0   2023-01-01 00:00:00     0
1   2023-01-01 00:10:00     0
2   2023-01-01 00:20:00     0
3   2023-01-01 00:30:00     0
4   2023-01-01 00:40:00     0
...     ...     ...
1292    2023-01-09 23:20:00     23
1293    2023-01-09 23:30:00     23
1294    2023-01-09 23:40:00     23
1295    2023-01-09 23:50:00     23
1296    2023-01-10 00:00:00     0

1297 rows × 2 columns
    DateWithTime    Hour
0   2023-01-01 00:00:00     0
1   2023-01-01 00:10:00     0
2   2023-01-01 00:20:00     0
3   2023-01-01 00:30:00     0
4   2023-01-01 00:40:00     0
...     ...     ...
1226    2023-01-09 12:20:00     12
1227    2023-01-09 12:30:00     12
1228    2023-01-09 12:40:00     12
1229    2023-01-09 12:50:00     12
1296    2023-01-10 00:00:00     0

703 rows × 2 columns
    DateWithTime    Hour
78  2023-01-01 13:00:00     13
79  2023-01-01 13:10:00     13
80  2023-01-01 13:20:00     13
81  2023-01-01 13:30:00     13
82  2023-01-01 13:40:00     13
...     ...     ...
1261    2023-01-09 18:10:00     18
1262    2023-01-09 18:20:00     18
1263    2023-01-09 18:30:00     18
1264    2023-01-09 18:40:00     18
1265    2023-01-09 18:50:00     18

324 rows × 2 columns
    DateWithTime    Hour
114     2023-01-01 19:00:00     19
115     2023-01-01 19:10:00     19
116     2023-01-01 19:20:00     19
117     2023-01-01 19:30:00     19
118     2023-01-01 19:40:00     19
...     ...     ...
1291    2023-01-09 23:10:00     23
1292    2023-01-09 23:20:00     23
1293    2023-01-09 23:30:00     23
1294    2023-01-09 23:40:00     23
1295    2023-01-09 23:50:00     23

270 rows × 2 columns
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the normalized date to get the time as timedelta, then `cut` and `groupby`:

```
# ensure datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# form bins, split groups
bins = ['0', '12h', '18h', '24h']
labels = [f'{bins[i]}-{bins[i+1]}' for i in range(len(bins)-1)]
out = dict(list(df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Date'].sub(df['Date'].dt.normalize()),
                                  [pd.Timedelta(x) for x in bins],
                                  labels=labels, include_lowest=True))))
```

Output:

```
{'0-12h':                     Date
          0    2023-01-01 00:00:00
          1    2023-01-01 00:10:00
          2    2023-01-01 00:20:00
          3    2023-01-01 00:30:00
          4    2023-01-01 00:40:00
          ...                  ...
          1221 2023-01-09 11:30:00
          1222 2023-01-09 11:40:00
          1223 2023-01-09 11:50:00
          1224 2023-01-09 12:00:00
          1296 2023-01-10 00:00:00
          
          [658 rows x 1 columns],
'12h-18h':                     Date
           73   2023-01-01 12:10:00
           74   2023-01-01 12:20:00
           75   2023-01-01 12:30:00
           76   2023-01-01 12:40:00
           77   2023-01-01 12:50:00
           ...                  ...
           1256 2023-01-09 17:20:00
           1257 2023-01-09 17:30:00
           1258 2023-01-09 17:40:00
           1259 2023-01-09 17:50:00
           1260 2023-01-09 18:00:00
           
           [324 rows x 1 columns],
'18h-24h':                     Date
           109  2023-01-01 18:10:00
           110  2023-01-01 18:20:00
           111  2023-01-01 18:30:00
           112  2023-01-01 18:40:00
           113  2023-01-01 18:50:00
           ...                  ...
           1291 2023-01-09 23:10:00
           1292 2023-01-09 23:20:00
           1293 2023-01-09 23:30:00
           1294 2023-01-09 23:40:00
           1295 2023-01-09 23:50:00
           
           [315 rows x 1 columns],
}
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-01-10', freq='10min')})
```